# importing beautiful soup in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, sys.path

I am trying to import beautifulsoup in python3. I have this line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

It says:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 175
except Exception, e:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I see that it is still trying to use python2.7 package. I have installed beautifulsoup for python3 using pip3 and on checking I found that the package is there in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/.
Also on checking sys.path, I found that this path is present. Still I don't get why it is trying to use the older package,

Comment: Presumably in `sys.path` the old 2.7 path is there before the new py4 one -- quite a problem!  Maybe a bad `PYTHONPATH` in your OS's environment?  Please show us your `sys.path` and that env var to help us help you.  `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` fixed everything for me, but then, I don't have such "path cross-contamination", thanks be...!-)

Comment: Yeah. The old 2.7 path is there as pointed out by you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `python3` executable has `python2.7` in `sys.path` then it means that the Python 3 installation is broken.

Here's [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) on my machine:

```
['',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Note: no `python2.7` directories.

Make sure `PYTHONPATH` is not set, and there are no stray `.pth` files in the default list (installation-dependent, above) of Python 3.4 directories that mention python2.7 directories, and [`PYTHONSTARTUP` file](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) or `sitecustomize`, `usercustomize` modules do not corrupt `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using virtualenv can temporarily solve your problem.
Or maybe try `pip uninstall beautifulsoup4`
That way you're only left with the version pip3 installed.